# Why does the Rails increment method doesn't save the changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, updown

I have this code to implement a thumbs `up/down` functionality in my rails app

```
if params[:vote][:type] == "up"
    answer = Answer.find_by_id(params[:vote][:id])
    answer.increment(:ups)
    render text: answer.ups
end
if params[:vote][:type] == "down"
    answer = Answer.find_by_id(params[:vote][:id])
    answer.increment(:downs)
    render text: answer.downs
end
```

It doesn't give any error but the incremented value is not updated in the DB.

This code works properly in rails console.

Please help,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you please write the schema of your model, I mean fields with datatype

another migration with:

```
change_column :answers, :ups, :integer, :default: 0
change_column :answers, :downs, :integer, :default: 0
```

might help you

Comment: create_table "answers", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "answer_data"
    t.integer  "ups"
    t.integer  "downs"
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

Comment: increment/decrement fields should have default value 0 otherwise it wont work

Comment: i've used a method that keeps 0 as the value of up / down. the method is called before saving the model

Comment: Oh yea there's the problem..before saving a method runs that resets the values to 0..sorry..was a silly mistake

Comment: I have tested keeping null as default value. 
  increment! method is working

  please make sure answer.increment!(:ups) is executed, I mean if params[:vote][:type] == "up" returns true

Comment: yea..ran the migration..everything is working fine..thanks again

Answer (score 3):

this is [by design](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment). The method increments the attribute but does not save. Use `increment!` ([bang version](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21)) if you want to save as well.

Comment: the increment! method returns true still the DB doesn't reflect the changes

Comment: if it does not act as documented, i guess your problem lies somewhere else. Try to increment the thing manually and save. If it does not work, maybe there's a problem with your column definition.

Answer (score 1):

Check it  once

```
if params[:vote][:type] == "up"
    answer = Answer.find_by_id(params[:vote][:id])
    answer.to_i.increment(:ups)
    render text: answer.ups
elsif params[:vote][:type] == "down"
    answer = Answer.find_by_id(params[:vote][:id])
    answer.to_i.increment(:downs)
    render text: answer.downs
end
```

Comment: Answer is a model with attributes like answer_data, ups, downs etc..so i can't convert it to integer..i even tried calling answer.save after answer.increment but it still doesn't work